# Finding if a target number is the sum of two numbers in an array via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

A basic solution would look like this:

```
bool sortTest(int[] numbers, int target)
{
    Array.Sort(numbers);
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
       for(int j = numbers.Length-1; j > i; j--)
       {
           if(numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target)
               return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I'm very new to LINQ but this is what I have written so far:

```
var result = from num in numbers
             where numbers.Contains(target -num)
             select num;
if (result.Count() > 0)
    return true;

return false;
```

Now i'm running into an issue given the following example:
Array: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8
Target: 16

It should return back false, but it's catching 16-8=8. So how do I go about not letting it notice itself in the contains check? Or can I make a second array each time within the query that doesn't contain the number I'm working with(thus solving the problem)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var result = from n1 in numbers
             from n2 in numbers
             where n1 != n2 && n1 + n2 == target
             select new { n1, n2 };
```

[Edit]
This returns matches twice and ignores the situation where a number is duplicated in the array.  You can't handle these situations using Expression Syntax because you can't access the index of a matched item, but you can do it like this:

```
var result = numbers.Select((n1, idx) => 
    new {n1, n2 = numbers.Take(idx).FirstOrDefault(
    n2 => n1 + n2 == target)}).Where(pair => pair.n2 != 0);
```

As long as you don't have any zeros in your array.

[Further thought Edit]

The perfect mix solution:

```
var result = from item in numbers.Select((n1, idx) =>
                 new {n1, shortList = numbers.Take(idx)})
             from n2 in item.shortList
             where item.n1 + n2 == target
             select new {n1 = item.n1, n2};
```

Comment: Nice  :)  You seem a lot more awake than I am this morning +1

Comment: One thing: What if the array contains two numbers that are equal and would add up to the target? Ex: The array contained 2 8's and the target was 16. Other than that, your statement was awesome and helped me out a lot.

Comment: Yeah, it also returns any matching pair twice: ie. 4 + 8 = 12; 8 + 4 = 12. I'm just trying to figure out an even better answer.

Answer (score 4):

What I'd do to solve this problem in general is first write a "chooser".

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chooser<T>(this IList<T> sequence, int num)
{ ... left as an exercise ... }
```

The output of the chooser is a sequence of sequences. Each sub-sequence is of length num, and consists of elements chosen from the original sequence. So if you passed { 10, 30, 20, 50 } as the sequence and 3 for num, you'd get the sequence of sequences:

```
{10, 30, 20}, {10, 30, 50}, {10, 20, 50}, {30, 20, 50}
```

as a result.

Once you've written Chooser, the problem becomes easy:

```
var results = 
  from subsequence in numbers.Chooser(2)
  where subsequence.Sum() == target
  select subsequence;
```

And now you can solve the problem for subsequences of other sizes, not just pairs.

Writing Chooser is a bit tricky but it's not *too* hard.

Answer (score 2):

To improve on pdr's reply and address the concerns mentioned in the comments you could use the [overloaded Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) to compare the indices of the items and ensure uniqueness.

```
public bool sortTest(int[] numbers, int target)
{
    var indexedInput = numbers.Select((n, i) => new { Number = n, Index = i });

    var result = from x in indexedInput
                 from y in indexedInput
                 where x.Index != y.Index
                 select x.Number + y.Number == target;

    return result.Any(item => item);
}
```

Or in dot notation:

```
var result = numbers.Select((n, i) => new { Number = n, Index = i })
                    .SelectMany(
                        x => indexedInput,
                        (x, y) => new { x = x,  y = y })
                    .Where(item => item.x.Index != item.y.Index)
                    .Select(item => item.x.Number + item.y.Number == target);
```